# sender receives receipt/autoresonder with custom fields

Tags: php

I recently changed the PHP code where the submitter receives a receipt, Now they want the submitter to receive it with less fields than what the E-mail goes to.

For example the people who get the email from the submitter sees all the fields, but the submitter gets a receipt with different fields. I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated. So I receive all this fields name,lastname,email,Phone,ReferredBy. But the submitter receives only these files name,lastname,ReferredBy

```
  <?php
  // OPTIONS - PLEASE CONFIGURE THESE BEFORE USE!

 $yourEmail = "example1@email,example2@email.com"; // the email address you wish to      receive these mails through
 $yourWebsite = "Application"; // the name of your website
 $thanksPage = ''; // URL to 'thanks for sending mail' page; leave empty to keep message on the same page 
  $maxPoints = 4; // max points a person can hit before it refuses to submit - recommend 4
$requiredFields = "name,lastname,email,Phone,ReferredBy";                            // names of the fields you'd like to be required as a minimum, separate each field with a comma

 $textlink ='<a href="confirmation.html">Click Here And Take The Next Step</a>.' ; 
// DO NOT EDIT BELOW HERE
$error_msg = array();
 $result = null;

$requiredFields = explode(",", $requiredFields);

 function clean($data) {
$data = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data)));
return $data;
}
function isBot() {
$bots = array("Indy", "Blaiz", "Java", "libwww-perl", "Python", "OutfoxBot", "User-Agent",      "PycURL", "AlphaServer", "T8Abot", "Syntryx", "WinHttp", "WebBandit", "nicebot", "Teoma", "alexa",    "froogle", "inktomi", "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory", "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot", "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz");

foreach ($bots as $bot)
    if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false)
        return true;

if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == " ")
    return true;

return false;
}

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
if (isBot() !== false)
    $error_msg[] = "No bots please! UA reported as: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

// lets check a few things - not enough to trigger an error on their own, but worth assigning a spam score.. 
// score quickly adds up therefore allowing genuine users with 'accidental' score through but cutting out real spam :)
$points = (int)0;

$badwords = array("adult");

foreach ($badwords as $word)
    if (
        strpos(strtolower($_POST['comments']), $word) !== false || 
        strpos(strtolower($_POST['name']), $word) !== false
    )
        $points += 2;

if (strpos($_POST['comments'], "http://") !== false || strpos($_POST['comments'], "www.") !== false)
    $points += 2;
if (isset($_POST['nojs']))
    $points += 1;
if (preg_match("/(<.*>)/i", $_POST['comments']))
    $points += 2;
if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3)
    $points += 1;
if (strlen($_POST['comments']) < 15 || strlen($_POST['comments'] > 1500))
    $points += 2;
if (preg_match("/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{7,}/i", $_POST['comments']))
    $points += 1;
// end score assignments

foreach($requiredFields as $field) {
    trim($_POST[$field]);

    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || empty($_POST[$field]) && array_pop($error_msg) != "Please fill in all the required fields and submit again.\r\n")
        $error_msg[] = "Please fill in all the required fields and submit again.";
}

if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name'])))
    $error_msg[] = "The name field must not contain special characters.\r\n";

if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email'])))
    $error_msg[] = "That is not a valid e-mail address.\r\n";



if ($error_msg == NULL && $points <= $maxPoints) {
    $subject = "Payment";

    $message = "New applicant: \n\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            foreach ($val as $subval) {
                $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($subval) . "\r\n";
            }
        } else {
            $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";
        }
    }
    $message .= "\r\n";

    // this means reply to the sender with e-mail and subject.
if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win")) {
$headers   = "From: {$_POST['email']}\r\n";
$headers  .= "Bcc: $yourEmail\r\n";
$headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}\r\n";
 } else {
$headers   = "From: {$_POST['email']}\r\n";
$headers  .= "Bcc: $yourEmail\r\n";
$headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}\r\n";
 }

if (mail($_POST['email'],$subject,$message,$headers)) {
        if (!empty($thanksPage)) {
            header("Location: $thanksPage");
            exit;
        } else {
            $result = 'Congratulations! We have received your application.     IMPORTANT Click link below';

            $disable = true;
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg[] = 'Your mail could not be sent this time. ['.$points.']';
    }
} else {
    if (empty($error_msg))
        $error_msg[] = 'Your mail looks too much like spam, and could not be sent this    time. ['.$points.']';
}
 }
 function get_data($var) {
if (isset($_POST[$var]))
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$var]);
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: your name and email check will exclude many legit names and email addresses

Comment: The emails, that i put are not real emails. just an example.